# Rails 5. Update association with exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-associations

I have a one-to-many relationship between the classes `P`(parent) and `C`(childs).

Table `C` has a unique composite index `{p_id, somerow}`.

Having 2 objects of class `P` (`p1` and `p2`), I want to combine them into one, doing this through
`p2.childs.update_all (parent: p1)`, but I get a rollback of the transaction, because the uniqueness of the composite index is violated. However, from the point of view of internal logic, this situation is not an error, and a duplicate entry, instead of changing the parent, must be destroyed.

What is the most correct way to solve the problem?

P.S. The number of requests to the database is critical.

P.P.S. The number of children in the relation can exceed the value in 1k records.

Comment: You want `p1 = p1 & p2`? and also `p1.childs = p1.childs & p2.childs`? `&` means "combined". Then, afterwards you want `p2.destroy`? do you also want `p2.childs.destroy_all`?

Comment: Exactly. I want to merge.
All `p2` children whose duplicates are not present in `p1` must be added, and duplicates must be removed.

Comment: How do you determine if some of `p2.children` will be removed; is it if `somerow` already has a duplicate?

Comment: The value of `somerow` must be unique for each `children` within the same `parent`.
With such a merger, all `children` of the parent `p2` must be assigned to the parent `p1`, which leads to a violation of uniqueness.

Comment: I don't want to put this into answer just yet as this is more of validating still what you want, but is this logic what you want to achieve: `p2.childs.where(somerow: p1.childs.pluck(:somerow)).destroy_all`, then next line is `p2.childs.update_all(parent: p1)` First line removes all p2 children first that is already duplicate/present in p1 children. Then the second line would not raise a uniqueness constraint error anymore because they all got destroyed already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to validate records by Rails, which means execute a separate query to validate each record, here is a straightforward way to do it:

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :somerow, scope: :p_id

  belongs_to :p
end

class P < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs

  def merge_sibling(p2)
    p2.childs.each do |c|
      c.p_id = self.id
      c.valid? ? c.save : c.destroy
    end
    p2.destroy
  end
end

p1.merge_sibling p2
```